# Is max_depth in scikit the equivalent of pruning in decision trees?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, decision-trees, supervised-learning

I was analyzing the classifier created using a decision tree. There is a tuning parameter called [max_depth](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) in scikit's decision tree. Is this equivalent of pruning a decision tree? If not, how could I prune a decision tree using scikit?

```
dt_ap = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1, max_depth=13)
boosted_dt = AdaBoostClassifier(dt_ap, random_state=1)
boosted_dt.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: I have succeeded in implementing Cost complexity pruning on Sklearn's model, and here is the link: https://github.com/appleyuchi/Decision_Tree_Prune
you may like it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29256)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this equivalent of pruning a decision tree?

Though they have similar goals (i.e. placing some restrictions to the model so that it doesn't grow very complex and overfit), `max_depth` **isn't** equivalent to pruning. The way pruning usually works is that go back through the tree and replace branches that do not help with leaf nodes.

> If not, how could I prune a decision tree using scikit?

You can't through scikit-learn (without altering the source code).
Quote taken from the [Decision Tree documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html): *Mechanisms such as pruning (not currently supported)*

If you want to post-prune a tree you have to do it on your own:
You can read this [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428469/pruning-decision-trees) detailing how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Now with the new version 0.22.1, you can! It does pruning based on minimal cost-complexity pruning: the subtree with the largest cost complexity that is smaller than ccp_alpha will be chosen.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html